# Composite function derivatives

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

Is this statment right in derivative of compoaite three functions $(f \circ g \circ h)'(x) = (f\circ g)' (h(x))$

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so. At least not in general case:

1. $ (f \circ g \circ h)' (x) = f'(g(h(x)))\  g'(h(x))\ h'(x) $
2. $ (f \circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))\ g'(x)$

so, it follows $(f \circ g)'(h(x)) = f'(g(h(x)))\ g'(h(x))$. It's quite similar to (1) but not the same. It would be the same, for example, when $h'(x) = 1$.

Comment: Is $ d/dx((f \circ g \circ h) (x) )=$$   d/d(h(x))((f \circ g)(h(x))$ ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not right.

Set $F=f \circ g$. Then, by the usual chain rule,
$$
(f \circ g \circ h)'(x) = (F \circ h)'(x) = F'(h(x)) \, h'(x) = (f \circ g)'(h(x)) \, h'(x). 
$$

Comment: Is $$ d/dx((f∘g∘h)(x))$$ $$ = d/d(h(x))((f∘g)(h(x))$$

Comment: @MarkWilYuan: No, why do you think that? That's not what I wrote. You need to differentiate $f \circ g$ too.

Comment: No, I meant the right hand side is derivative with respect to x and the left hand side is the derivative with reapect to h(x) not x are they equal?

Comment: Oh, I misread. But what does it even *mean* to differentiate with respect to a function? That notation doesn't make sense, in my opinion.

Comment: Are you sure,,, for example if y=x and we want to find the derivative with respect to x^2 we can find it   as follow  let y=sqr(x^2) when x >0   so dy/d(x^2)= 1/(2 sqr(x^2))=1/(2x),,, so we can find the derivative with respect to a function

Comment: Well, in principle you could do that (and some people do), but I think that notation is terrible. We have functions $f$ (of one variable) and their derivatives $f'$. Period. If the variable happens to have a name, say you write the function as $f(x)$, you can alternatively write the derivative as $df/dx$. If you change the variable like you do, you are creating a new function (a composite function which in the end depends on $y$), say $g(y)=f(\sqrt{x})$, and its derivative should be written $g'$, or maybe $dg/dy$, in my opinion. But not $df/d(x^2)$.